# Given a Matrix Exponential w/ repeated E.Values, find Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Is it possible to find a matrix $A$ given an arbitrary matrix exponential $e^{tA}$?

It seems to me that this is definitely possible if $A$ has distinct eigenvalues. This is because

$$
e^{tA} = v_1 e^{t \lambda_1 } c_1 + v_2 e^{t \lambda_2 } c_2 + \;...\; + v_n e^{n \lambda_n } c_n
$$
for an $n$ x $n$ matrix $A$. So given $e^{tA}$ we are indirectly given the eigenvalues and eigenvectors.

Is this possible to do if $A$ has repeated eigenvalues?

Comment: Yes, take the derivative of $t\mapsto e^{tA}$ at $t=0$.

Comment: @omran I understand the question as meaning that only one value of $t$ is provided.

Comment: In this case, does [that](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/97564/is-the-matrix-exponential-map-injective) help answering the question (if $t$ or $A$ are allowed to be complex)?