# When is the exponential map between matrices injective?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, exponential-function, matrix-exponential

Consider a complex matrix $A$. When does $e^A=e^B$ imply $A=B$?

Is there any general statement that can be made as to when this holds?

It is clearly not true in general, a trivial example being when $A$ and $B$ are diagonal in the same basis but with eigenvalues differing by $2\pi i\mathbb Z$. This is also mentioned [in this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/97565/173147).

[This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1592257/173147) also seems to provide an answer to this question, but I'm not familiar with the theory of Lie algebras so I'm not sure, and I wouldn't know how to translate it into more elementary statements about matrices (if that is even possible).

Comment: The answer of Yves *does* really provide an answer, in my opinion. This question should be considered within the area of Lie groups and Lie algebras.

Comment: @DietrichBurde if you are referring to the answer I linked, I'm not saying it doesn't. Rather, I'm asking whether that answer can be translated into the language of matrices for someone not familiar with Lie theory

Comment: No, you need "solvable" and "simply connected" and other properties from Lie groups, which should not be explained only with matrices, I think. There is topology and algebra, after all, not only matrices.

Comment: See [loup blanc's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/756282).

Answer (score 0):

This was addressed in [loup blanc's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/756282) to another question, although that question has a narrower setting than the current one.